# How to code this animation in css3?

Tags: css, animation, gif

it's been a long time I've last coded in html and css, that was before that lovely html5 and css3. So, in the early 2000's we made a logo in gif, what was so cool, and I've just found it on my PC. It would be nice to convert to pure css, instead of limited-size-gif but I have no idea how to start it.
[Here is my animated gif](http://tesztelo.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/wp.gif)

Could you give me first impressions, which css3 attributes  should I choose for it?
Thanks

Comment: You should at least provide some of your approaches to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the animation property with custom keyframes probably. Here is a rough example. I didn't spend much time on the animation. Thats your job ;)

https://codepen.io/bygrace1986/pen/POypXX

**HTML**

```
<div class="logo" data-logo="wp"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo {
  position: relative;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.logo::before, .logo::after {
  content: attr(data-logo);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
}

.logo::before {
  color: red;
  animation: rotate 1s infinite;
}

.logo::after {
  color: black;
  animation: rotate 1s infinite reverse;
}

@keyframes rotate { 
  0% {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  25% {
    left: 10%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 10%;
  }
  75% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```